# How can I stop Pandas from automatically converting my date format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file and the dates are stored like so:
`Saturday November 30, 2019`

However when I read in the excel file to a dataframe the dates are converted to the following format:

`Date        Deer Lake  Dartmouth  Grand Falls 
2019-11-30     0.7917     0.7663       0.7805`

Why is this happening? Does pandas have an option to prevent any reformatting?

How I'm reading the excel file: `df = pd.read_excel("RunningTotals_test.xlsx", keep_default_na=False, sheet_name=sheet_name)`

Comment: in your `read_csv` call, use the `dtypes` parameter and set it as string

Comment: I'm using `read_excel` but it is the same I assume. Would I do this?: `df = pd.read_excel("RunningTotals_test.xlsx", sheet_name=sheet_name, dtype= str)`

Comment: Since your other columns are numbers, I'd recommend using the dictionary version of dtype.  so, what you have except for `dtype={"Date":str}` or `dtype={'date:'object`}

Comment: I tried that as well as my version, but nothing is changing :s

Comment: I can see no advantage to not having pandas convert the object into a date object. What you're seeing in the view of the dataframe is just a display format, not how the data is actually stored in the dataframe.

Comment: Ok, so when I *write* this dataframe with the `dtype` parameter to an excel sheet the format will be the desired one?

Comment: You'd have to try it. Pandas will default to outputting a full timestamp. You can set the display format of that column to be the same as your original, and it will look identical.

Comment: How do I set it to be the same?

Comment: Okay I figured it out, I'm using pd.to_datetime to do the work I'll post the solution

Answer (score 5):

dtype parameter must be a dictionary, try this:

```
pd.read_excel("RunningTotals_test.xlsx", sheet_name=sheet_name, dtype= {"Column1": str, "Column2": int, ...})
```

Comment: Note, that it doesn't have to be a dictionary(though the individual value behavior would be undesirable in this case), and you don't have to set the value for every column if you want to leave the default for some columns.

Comment: Yup I tried this version too but nothing is changing

Comment: oh... Are you dates in excel as a date, or as a string?  Excel can display dates in a variety of formats, but they are stored as numbers in the file, so pandas just converts them to dates. Convert your excel file dates to strings, and pandas shouldn't autoconvert

Comment: Ah I forgot to address that, the dates are formulas, I'm guessing I set evaluate_formulas to true so I get the correct content. I recall there was a parameter like that

Comment: Okay I figured it out, I'm using `pd.to_datetime` to do the work I'll post the solution

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it with Pandas' `to_datetime` function, although this doesn't stop Pandas from the conversion it works:

```
df = pd.read_excel("RunningTotals_test.xlsx", keep_default_na=False, sheet_name=sheet_name)
df['Date '] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date ']) # convert the column to a datetime object
df['Date '] = df['Date '].dt.strftime('%A %B %d, %Y') # format the object
```

Output:

```
Date                          Deer Lake  Dartmouth  Grand Falls   
Saturday November 30, 2019     0.7917     0.7663       0.7805
```